# How to align tab text at center in android

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me how to align tab text in the center in android? I had given  `android:gravity="center"` for `LinearLayout` and `TabWidget`. It is still not working. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: add here what you tried.full code.

Comment: Here this link http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136 refers the tutorial for custom tab view. In this tab the tab text is placed in center.

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
    int tabCount = tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount();
     for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {
   final View view = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i);
    if ( view != null ) {
    // reduce height of the tab
    view.getLayoutParams().height *= 0.66;

    //  get title text view
    final View textView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    if ( textView instanceof TextView ) {
        // just in case check the type

        // center text
        ((TextView) textView).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        // wrap text
        ((TextView) textView).setSingleLine(false);

        // explicitly set layout parameters
        textView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
        textView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: tabHost does not seem to work anymore, what is the current solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_gravity="center"`